# Shrink partition with gparted

Tags: ext4, gparted

I've seen a lot of posts about discrepancies between du, df, and gparted, but none really answer my question, so here it is.

I've a bootable drive of 8gb that needs to be reduced in size to fit a 4gb new drive.

It's for an embedded system, and it's a real pain to recreate the drive from scratch, I just want to dd one onto the other.

This should all be easy as the full system only uses 2.8gb.

But gparted won't allow me.

Here's a screenshot of gparted with the partition mounted:
[image]

and this is what happens after I right click and unmount the partition:
[image]

It's a little frustrating because I know there's 1.1gb free, and I only have to shrink it by another 300mb to be safe.

So, why is that??

Comment: It looks like your /dev/sda1 partition is already below 4GB?  Or is it 3.9GiB in parted 4.19GB, and the drive is 4.0GB?

Comment: You could always try running "resize2fs" directly...  That wouldn't change the size of the partition, only the filesystem, but it might allow parted to shrink the partition itself?

Comment: The new drive is "4GB", but actually only 3.7 usable, so I need at least another 200mb back.
`resize2fs` says "The filesystem is already 1022208 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!"

Comment: If resize2fs already says the filesystem has been reduced, then you could "dd" 1922208x4KB blocks to the new USB, and ignore the partition size